# Bootstrap dropdown toggling wrong element if a href contains id of existing element, is it a bug?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, href

I have a dropdown menu that is usable even without JS enabled. For that I've created a copy of the menu in the footer with all submenus opened and added `<a name="nojs-menu"></a>` on top of that menu and have first level of the main menu point to that anchor: `<a href="#nojs-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">`. This way whenever JS wasn't executed my main menu will just drop users to the footer where all submenus are opened.

Now, [HTML5 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) recommends replacing `name` attributes with `id`. But as soon as I do that dropdown menus stop working because they toggle `open` class not on submenu but on the anchor with id `nojs-menu`. Is it a bug or did I misunderstood something?

Bootstrap version in 3.3.5.

Comment: if you replace name with id it is not working because the id and the href value '#nojs-menu' are exactly same

Comment: But that's the point. I want the links to fallback to move user on the needed place on the page if JS is not working. And what's the logic behind toggling some completely different element on page if that's intentional?

Comment: can you try once adding some other selector like class or id in the child menu. The child menu only have one identifier which is conflicting with the parent href

Comment: Ok, I've found it, setting id for every submenu and placing it in `data-target`s of top menu buttons works. You helped me do this, so you can write the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: no problem.. You can add this in anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case all submenu items need an `id` and this ids must be in `data-target`s of top menu buttons.